# is there a way to suggest the spellchecker a preferred language in HTML?

Tags: html, google-chrome, spell-checking

I tried both `<html lang="de-DE">` and `<textarea lang="de-DE">` in Chrome but without success.

Is there something that I can do today to suggest a preferred language in a HTML textarea?

Comment: That should work in supported browsers.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms

Comment: is that working in chrome as well? apparently it gets ignored :(

Comment: The answer doesn't look like an answer to me, as it doesn't at all tell how to do it in Chrome :\

Comment: Related : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes) is the way to specify content language, for spellchecking and other purposes. However, browser support is limited.

In spellchecking, Chrome ignores the `lang` attribute and uses the language set in the browser settings. So it’s user-controllable, not author-controllable.

IE 10 and newer seem to honor the `lang` attribute, but if the system lacks support for the specified language, spellchecking is just turned off for the element.

Firefox has been [reported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) to honor `lang` from version 9, and it seems to do that, but inconsistencies have been detected. Moreover, for unknown languages, it does the same as IE. When I installed German spellchecking support (search with `deutsch` to find out some options), it started flagging typos in textareas declared with `lang=de` or `lang=de-DE` or `lang=de-AT`.